# Sending data from html to php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i try to send data actually checkboxes from html to AJAX and ajax will post it to PHP but it prints always null.

First of all,

```
<ul>
                {foreach value=mCast key=key from=$cast}
                {if $key lt $castCount-1}
                <li class="p16 pd_5 border_b"><a class="bordo" href="{$mCast.url}">{$mCast.nameSurname}</a> <a href="{$mCast.characterUrl}" class="sag bordo">{$mCast.characterName}</a>
                {else}

                <li class="p16 pd_5"><a class="bordo" href="{$mCast.url}">{$mCast.nameSurname}</a> <a class="sag bordo" href="{$mCast.characterUrl}">{$mCast.characterName}</a>
                {/if}
               <input align="right" type=checkbox name="checkArtist[]" id ="{$movieId}-{$mCast.id}"></li>
                {/foreach}
                <a style="float: right" href='javascript:void(null);' onclick="deleteData2();" >
                    <input type="button" name="checkArtistButton" value="Sil"></a>
            </ul>
```

Dont care about foreach tag they are template_lite tags.

then when i send this data to deleteData2 and deleteData2 has:

```
 function deleteData2()
    {
        var data = {
            'artistId[]' : []
        };    
        $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
            data['artistId[]'].push($(this).val());
        }); 


        $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2',data,function(response){
            alert("silindi");
        })


    }
```

For example when i try to cut this ajax code some part in console it prints
[image]

and in my php side i try this ,

```
  echo '<pre>';

        var_dump($_POST);
```

prints null. Why :s

Comment: $_POST is a server array... you should access the data using the index.

Comment: Whats the form action/method? Are you POSTing for the method, or GETing? Request for additional code, please.

Comment: I think you should change "artistId[]" by "artistId" in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try With Php example. Sometimes Encoding creates problem or error in Html. Check the proper tags. All Tags should closed.